# Regex in lex [^a-z]*

Tags: regex, lex

For the given regex, `[^a-z]*` in `lex`, the question is will it match any word not containing any lower case letter, or this is not the correct implementation? I.e., for that specific scenario, should the given regex be used, or this is a proper one for matching a word that has no lower case letters: `[^a-z]+`?

My reasoning is that it is not, it should be `+` instead of the `*`, since the negation of range, with 0 or more possible cases. seems wrong. But it's hard to get my mind on why is it wrong. I tried several regex tools online, and its hit and miss, some manage to show that it works, some show more matches between characters.

I would say that negating a lowercase string, and saying its either 0 or more of those, that would match the string `abc` as well, since it (does satisfy the scenario that it doesn't have 0 of anything. That could be said for any string. `+` seems like a more intuitive option, but in this case `*` was used and I think its an incorrect implementation, but can't find any resources to back it up since Google doesn't play nicely with those search strings.

Some test cases, this is is node.js:

```
/[^a-z]*$/.test('testTEST123') - True
/[^a-z]*$/.test('test') - True (this one should be false as per problem statement)
/[^a-z]+$/.test('testTEST123') - True
/[^a-z]+$/.test('test') - False (this one is correct, so there are no matches that dont satisfy the regex)
```

On regex101.com, the results are similar, but the highlighted part is the end of the line, although there are no characters there.

I dont know is there some specific lex implementation of regex that is different, but as I described, something feels wrong with * usage for not-matching the range.

Comment: What's the question here? `*` means 0 or more, `+` means 1 or more. `*` will match any string, including empty ones

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this. Make a regex `[a-z]` and see if the string contains any matches.

Comment: @Stefan to rephrase the question, does the provided regex does only matching a string that has no lowercase letters, or in order to have that behaviour, the + should be used?

Comment: @4castle I know it sounds a bit too much. I encountered this regex on one place, its an awkward way to do it, but I wanted to see is there something specific in lex, or maybe my misunderstanding. For the matching of word without lowercase letters, should the given regex be used or the one with + instead of *

Comment: I'm not familiar with any specifics of lex, but the regex you probably need is `^[^a-z]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(F)lex rules never match the empty string, so it does not make any difference whether you use `*` or `+` in this context.

But I don't think the question captures the behaviour. A (f)lex rule matches the longest string matching any pattern and `[^a-z]+` will match any sequence of characters, whether punctuation, white space, unprintable control codes, etc., *except* lower-case letters. (In other words, it does not just match "words" unless you have an unusual definition of "word".

Comment: So, with this analogy, is it wrong to say [^a-z]* will evaluate to true, i.e. even if we have a pure lower case word, like 'test' there will still be a match since we can say that string has 0 of something (which is one of the conditions that satisfy the *), since its pretty much irrelevant what is inside the [ ] in this case?

And to add, by lex I was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software) I am not really familiar with flex

Comment: @wont: As I said, 0-length matches don't count in lex. So although in theory the pattern matches zero bytes, it will never be the selected match. ("Evaluates to true" is meaningless in the context of lex. Lex always selects the longest match, even if two patterns both match some prefix of the input.)